# join with where Vs join keyword in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

For joining tables I have always used the following approach:

```
Select e.name, e.surname, sum(s.gross) as sum_gross, AVG(s.gross) as avg_gross
from departments d
    join employees e
        on d.depid = e.depid
    join salaries s 
        on e.employeeid = s.personid
    group by e.name,e.surname
```

But now I saw some people who do it in the following way:

```
Select e.name, e.surname, sum(s.gross) as sum_gross, AVG(s.gross) as avg_gross
from departments d, employees e, salaries s
where d.depit = e.depid
and e.employeeid = s.personid
group by e.name,e.surname
```

I just want to make sure they are exactly the same and which one is preferred and is the best practice?

Comment: Your method is the standard and preferred method.

Comment: I'll prefer the first one :) If data is increased second query will execute slowly

Answer (score 1):

They produce the same execution plan. The first query is the preferred syntax since the [SQL-92 revision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92).